# Question about Gaussian Bound.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The question is the following:

If $ Y \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, then $ E\{\left|Y \right|I(\left|Y \right|>c)\} \le \sigma e^{-c^2/2\sigma^2}$.

I try to use Cauchy-Schwatz inequality and Gaussian tail bound but seems like not right approach. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the pdf of $Y$ and the fact that $|Y|1_{|Y|>c}$ is symmetric about $0$, we have
$$ \mathbb{E}[|Y|1_{|Y|>c}]=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_c^{\infty}ye^{-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma^2}}\;dy$$
Setting $u=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{y}{\sigma})^2$, this becomes
$$ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma\int_{\frac{c^2}{2\sigma^2}}^{\infty}e^{-u}\;du=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
and this is less than $\sigma e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ since $\frac{2}{\pi}<1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathrm{I}=\mathbf{E}\left(|Y|\mathbf{1}_{\{|Y|>c\}}\right)=2\int\limits_c^\infty dy\ y \dfrac{e^{-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma};$ make the change of variable $u = \dfrac{y^2}{2\sigma^2}$ so $du = \dfrac{y}{\sigma^2}$ and so, $\mathrm{I}=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\sigma\int\limits_{\frac{c}{\sigma^2}}^\infty du\ e^{-u}=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\sigma e^{-\frac{c}{2\sigma^2}}.$